# Entity Framework with Microsoft Access

Tags: entity-framework, ms-access, connection-string

I use .accdb file. I created class

```
using System.Data.Entity;

    class MSADbContext:DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    }
```

and add connectionString

```
<add name="MSADbContext" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\SportsStore.accdb" providerName="System.Data.OleDb"/>
```

After first query to DB I get the ProviderIncompatibleException: "calling "get_ProviderFactory" in repository typeOf "System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection" returns null"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your connection-string would be for an .mdb (Access 2003-) file. Check connection [strings here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/access/)

You need the ACE OLEDB provider. Standard Security:

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\myFolder\myAccess2007file.accdb;
Persist Security Info=False;
```

However, read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197259/does-microsoft-jet-db-work-with-entity-framework) first:

> Entity Framework does not support OLEDB connections, so your
>   connection string will not work. It is practically impossible to get
>   Entity Framework to collaborate with MS Access.

**practically impossible** is very compelling.

Answer (score 9):

OLEDB cannot support entity framework because entity framework needs that the entity framework provider generates the right queries for the specific database (while OLEDB is general DB access). You need a specific provider for Microsoft Access.

You can find a Microsoft Access Entity Framework Provider here
https://jetentityframeworkprovider.codeplex.com/

**EDIT**
The Access EF provider is now hosted on GitHub
https://github.com/bubibubi/JetEntityFrameworkProvider

Comment: Given the announcement that [CodePlex will be shutting down](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bharry/2017/03/31/shutting-down-codeplex/) will you be moving your project to GitHub?

Comment: I didn't see it. I will move it to github. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I know that this question was asked long ago but it seems that the author of original package (JetEntityFrameworkProvider) has developed a new Access EF provider called [EntityFrameworkCore.Jet](https://github.com/bubibubi/EntityFrameworkCore.Jet)