# MVC Connection String Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ms-access, database-connection, connection-string

I'm having an issue with my connection string using MVC 4 and access DB.  When I use the provider name  - System.Data.OleDb I still receive an error and when I remove it I get the below error.  I used the connection string from connectionstrings.com.

Any help is much appreciated.  Thanks

Here is the error:
The connection string 'EmployeeContext' in the application's configuration file does not 
contain the required providerName attribute."

Here is the connection string:

```
<add name="EmployeeContext" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=H:\Databases\EmployeeDb.mdb"/>
```

Comment: Are you using EntityFramework?

Comment: Yes added the references and still searching for answers

Comment: If it's any help my connection string for an EF connection looks like this: <add name="XXXXContext" connectionString="metadata=res://*/XXXXModel.csdl|res://*/XXXXModel.ssdl|res://*/XXXXModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=localhost;initial catalog=YYYY;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>. This is using SQL Server as the database, but shows the providerName attribute. I usually let Vistal Studio create the connection strings.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Microsoft Jet DB work with Entity Framework?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197259/does-microsoft-jet-db-work-with-entity-framework)

Comment: I'm thinking it will not because i'm not seeing any topics using that.  When I set it up with sql works fine but wanted to use access for client to have something light weight

Comment: @GordThompson that was the correct answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197259/does-microsoft-jet-db-work-with-entity-framework what I'm trying to do will not work based on that article

Answer (score 0):

Try this bro :

```
<add name="EmployeeContext" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=H:\Databases\EmployeeDb.mdb" providerName="System.Data.OleDb"/>
```

Comment: This was the error posted after using that provider name "A null was returned after calling the 'get_ProviderFactory' method on a store provider instance of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection'. The store provider might not be functioning correctly."

Answer (score 0):

I think you forget to add (providerName) Parameter to you connection string. 
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"

```
<add name="EmployeeContext" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=H:\Databases\EmployeeDb.mdb" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```