# Entity Framework Database First Microsoft Access Database

Tags: c#, ms-access, ef-database-first

I am trying to use Database first with an Access Database. But there are only SQL Database options. Is it possible to use Database first with an Access Database?

Comment: Try go to app.config and add 1 more Connection String

Comment: There is still only SQL options on Entity Data Model Wizard

Comment: Try add file Access Database to project an open it

Comment: Flow here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11432488/how-to-use-entity-framework-for-ms-access-database

and here :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197259/does-microsoft-jet-db-work-with-entity-framework

Comment: Actually I think you can't. There is an Entity Framework provider for MS Access but it does not support DB First.

Answer (score 0):

You have to clone [this](https://github.com/bubibubi/JetEntityFrameworkProvider.git) repository to local and compile the solution

Then you will have to register the ADO.Net provider for MS Access in the machine.config, which can be found at:

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config

Search for:

```
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
    ....
    </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

And add the following line:

```
<add name="JetEntityFrameworkProvider" invariant="JetEntityFrameworkProvider" description="JetEntityFrameworkProvider" type="JetEntityFrameworkProvider.JetProviderFactory, JetEntityFrameworkProvider, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=756cf6beb8fe7b41"/>
```

If you have followed these Steps, you should be able to use Entity Framework with Access and DB-first.

Source: https://github.com/bubibubi/JetEntityFrameworkProvider/blob/master/docs/Enabling_db_first.md